# Notice: Undefined index: idformulario in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto_ind\modificar.php on line 11

Tags: php, html, mysql

Necesito ayuda. Me encuentro haciendo un proyecto en html.
Consiste en algo sencillo:
Una pagina medica que permita rellenar un formulario y almacenar los datos en una BD.
Tienes dos usuarios:

Admin: Consulta, da de alta, modifica y elimina

User:  Consulta y da de alta.

Mi problema se encuentra en la parte de modificar y eliminar.

Les muestro mi codigo: 
modificar.php

```
    <html>
<HEAD>

    <TITLE></TITLE>
    <Meta charset = "iso-8859-1">

<BODY background="fondo.jpg" width="800" height="1200">

    <?php 
    include ("conexion.php");
    $idFormulario=$_REQUEST['idformulario'];

    $consulta="SELECT * FROM form_test WHERE idformulario='$idFormulario'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

    $mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    ?>

<center>   

    <img src="pokemon.jpg"width=250 height=150 align=right> 
    </B>

    <form onsubmit="return validar();"; action="alta.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" >

    <FORM  id="form1"  name="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="alta.php" >
    <Table border=1>
    <TR>
    <TD>

    <div align=right>
    Fecha:   (DD/MM/YYYY)<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="dia" size=2>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span style="float:right">Edad: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="edad" size=2>  
    </span>
    <span style="float:right">Genero: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="genero" size=2>  
    </span>
    Nombre: <INPUT TYPE="texto"NAME="nombre"size=40><br>
<span style="float:right">Lateralidad: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="lateralidad" size=10>   
    </span> 
    <span style="float:right">Ocupacion: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="ocupacion" size=10>   
    </span>
    Nacimiento: <INPUT TYPE="texto"NAME="dian"size=10><br>
    <BR>    
    Domicilio: <INPUT TYPE="texto"NAME="domicilio"size=40><br>
    Nacionalidad: <INPUT TYPE="texto"NAME="nacionalidad"size=20><br>
    <BR>
    <span style="float:right">Telefono fijo: <INPUT TYPE="texto"NAME="telfijo"size=10>
    </span>
    Religion: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="religion" size=30>
    <BR>
    Correo: <INPUT TYPE="texto"NAME="correo"size=30></div>
    <BR>

    Telefono emergencias: <INPUT TYPE="texto"NAME="telemer"size=40> <BR>
    Persona emergencias: <INPUT TYPE="texto"NAME="personaemer"size=40> <BR>


    <BR><BR>    

    <BR>    

    </table>
    </TR>
    </TD>
    <BR><BR>    

    <INPUT TYPE="submit"><INPUT TYPE="reset">       

    </FORM>
</div>

</form>
</center>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

El error me aparece al momento de hacer click en la opción "modificar" de mi pagina web. EN especifico en la linea: $idFormulario=$_REQUEST['idformulario'];

Y mi OTRO problema es en el codigo: Elimina.php

```
 <?php
    include ("conexion.php");

        $idFormulario=$_REQUEST['idformulario'];

        $elimina="DELETE FROM form_test WHERE idformulario='$idFormulario'";
        $resultado=$conexion -> query($elimina);


        if($resultado){
            header("Location: consulta.php");   
        }
        else {
            echo "Error al actualizar los datos. Por favor revise";     
        }
    ?>
```

El problema que tengo ahí, es que el código NO me marca error, pero no hace nada. No elimina ni nada. 
Soy nuevo en esto y quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias de antemano.

PD: Ya he comprobado los datos de la BD y se encuentran escritos correctamente en mi codigo.

Comment: Para el caso del formulario no veo donde exista **idformulario**, pudieras revisar ese primer punto

Comment: y de paso decirnos ¿qué valor esperas recibir por dicha variable?

Answer (score 1):

- te recomiendo que separes el Frontend del Backend y será mucho mejor para ti.
- No envíes el formulario, envía los datos de los inputs.
- Si estas enviando los datos por medio del método POST entonces así los recibes

Código

```
<input type="text" name="idformulario" value="1" >


<?php 
    include ("conexion.php");

    # si se recibe por metodo POST
    $idFormulario = $_POST['idformulario'];
    # si se recibe por metodo GET
    $idFormulario = $_GET['idformulario'];


    $consulta="SELECT * FROM form_test WHERE idformulario='$idFormulario'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    # mostrar datos
    # ASSOC para obtener las columnas por nombre
    # mostrar datos
    # MYSQLI_ASSOC para obtener las columnas por nombre
    # MYSQLI_NUMBER para obtener las columnas por numero
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "Dato: ". $row['colum_name'];
    }
?>
```